# Explaining windows azure to layman or students

Tags: azure

I am looking for simple analogies to explain windows azure, app fabric, etc to students or layman person. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.
Thanks
N

Comment: Just could not stop to write this comment: "Why a layman want to know about Windows Azure?" :)

Comment: I made a 4-minute video a few years ago. It's *very* high-level, but it might help: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poDRw_Xi3Aw.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I would try and talk about how we *used* to build and maintain things.    Buying our own hardware, building it, programming it, and connecting it to the internet.  That's the old way.  Then, I would pivot into what cloud service providers are.  In a nutshell, they are just somebody else's servers.  Usually Amazons, Microsoft's or Googles servers.  AWS/Azure/GCP.

Here is a quick youtube video explaining it in layman's terms.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ERdeg8Sfv4

Cloud service providers offer web portal, a website, where folks can click and build services like storage, backup, DNS, database, more websites, load balancing, and - maybe the most popular - virtual machine hosting.

What makes CSPs so successful is economies of scale. CSPs will build huge data centers and engineer them to provide the kind of services that most businesses need. COntrast that to if every business were to build their own from scratch. There are however lots of challenges to these CSPs, like needing a lot more spare capacity and having to build something that fits everyone as opposed to something that fits a particular user. So, for a small business, whether they save money depends on their use case.  You might save more building from scratch, but then you'd have to train and pay folks to maintain your own servers.

One of the most revolutionary benefits that cloud service providers brought into the market is that purchasing additional capacity is much easier and faster. You might have taken weeks to buy hardware and install it at your location. Or if you are renting though traditional suppliers you might take a few hours to let them manually reconfigure things. However they now make everything automatic so you can get a new server within seconds. This have allowed businesses to build their applications to allow them to scale on demand. This means that they pay different amount of money for the services depending on how much they use. This have the ability to reduce costs but it again require more time to develop and maintain the more complex applications.